How to create a Sankey diagram in R where node colors are consistent for providers across different phases of a healthcare pathway?
I am working on a project where I need to visualize the flow of healthcare providers across different phases of a care pathway using a Sankey diagram in R. Each phase represents a step in the care process, and various providers are involved in each phase.
I would like to ensure that each provider is consistently colored throughout the diagram. That means if a provider appears in multiple phases (both as a source and a target), it should have the same color across all instances.
I have already managed to create a Sankey diagram using networkD3::sankeyNetwork(), and I can assign colors, but I haven't figured out how to make sure that the same provider gets the same color in every phase of the care process.
Here’s a simplified version of the code I am working with:
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# Load data
data <- read_excel("healthcare_data.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

# Create nodes and links
providers <- unique(c(data$Phase_Provider, data$Next_Phase_Provider))

nodes <- data.frame(name = providers)

links <- data %>%
  mutate(source = match(Phase_Provider, nodes$name) - 1,
         target = match(Next_Phase_Provider, nodes$name) - 1) %>%
  group_by(source, target) %>%
  summarise(value = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

# Assigning the same color to all nodes for now
nodes$color <- "#1f77b4"

# Create the Sankey diagram
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

What I want to achieve:

Each healthcare provider (identified by Phase_Provider or
Next_Phase_Provider) should have the same color in all phases (nodes)
where they appear.
The color assignment should be based on the
provider’s name, so every instance of the same provider across
different phases will always appear in the same color.

Questions:

How can I assign colors to nodes based on the provider's name and ensure that the same provider is colored consistently across different phases?
Is there a way to map a unique color to each provider using d3.scaleOrdinal() or another method in R?


RIght now your question isn't reproducible, so a specific, great answer isn't really possible. However, see if this resource helps.

You can use the NodeGroup argument to specify a column in your nodes data frame that defines which group each node belongs to, which will determine the color of each node. You can use an appropriate d3.scaleOrdinal() command as the value passed to the argument colourScale to explicitly choose which color to use for each group.
links <- 
  tibble::tribble(
  ~source, ~target, ~value,
  0,       3,       3,
  0,       5,       3,
  0,       5,       3,
  1,       3,       3,
  1,       4,       3,
  1,       5,       3,
  2,       3,       3,
  2,       4,       3,
  2,       5,       3
  )

nodes <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~name,        ~node_group,
    "ABC_phase1", "ABC",
    "DEF_phase1", "DEF",
    "GHI_phase1", "GHI",
    "ABC_phase2", "ABC",
    "DEF_phase3", "DEF",
    "GHI_phase4", "GHI"
  )

networkD3::sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value = "value",
  NodeID = "name",
  NodeGroup = "node_group",
  fontSize = 12,
  nodeWidth = 30
)
#> Links is a tbl_df. Converting to a plain data frame.
#> Nodes is a tbl_df. Converting to a plain data frame.



networkD3::sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value = "value",
  NodeID = "name",
  NodeGroup = "node_group",
  colourScale = 'd3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]).range(["#7d3945", "#e0677b", "#244457"])',
  fontSize = 12,
  nodeWidth = 30
)
#> Links is a tbl_df. Converting to a plain data frame.
#> Nodes is a tbl_df. Converting to a plain data frame.


